# Upload multiple images from a folder

Tags: jmeter

`Problem statement: Trying to upload all the images from a folder to my post request`

`Error statement: Getting access denied error`

**Header Manager Configuration:**

[image]

**Http Request Configuration:**

[image]

[image]

**Folder Content**

[image]

How to upload all the images and if there are multiple images how the header manage `X-File-Name` can be updated?

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using [Directory Listing Config](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/directory-listing/DirectoryListing.md) plugin, it acts pretty much like [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) but for folders instead of CSV files.

It will read the filename (or full path) to the file for each user for each iteration so next time the HTTP Request sampler will be executed it will upload a new file given you use the appropriate [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) in the "Files Upload" tab of the HTTP Request sampler and in the HTTP Header Manager

[image]

[image]

[image]

You can install Directory Listing Config plugin using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-plugins-manager)